# Quiver plot with slider in Bokeh

Tags: python, html, matplotlib

I have developed a code that works perfectly fine but now I want to show it to my professor without always having to take my computer with me. The code is:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.widgets import Slider, Button, RadioButtons

a = 0.5

X, Y = np.mgrid[0:1.05:0.025, 0:1.05:0.025]
varX = #Some equation with X, Y and a (as a parameter)
varY = #Some other equation

U = varX-X
V = varY-Y

length = np.sqrt(U**2 + V**2)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
Q = plt.quiver(X, Y, varX-X, varY-Y,
                color='r',
                scale=3*(2 ** .5), units='y')

plt.subplots_adjust(left=0.25, bottom=0.25)

plt.axis([0, 1, 0, 1])

axcolor = 'lightgoldenrodyellow'
axa = plt.axes([0.25, 0.10, 0.65, 0.03], axisbg=axcolor)

sa = Slider(axa, 'Alfa', 0, 1, valinit=a)

def update(val):
    a = sa.val

    varX = #Same equation as before
    varY = #Same equation

    Q.set_UVC(varX - X, varY - Y)
    fig.canvas.draw_idle()

sa.on_changed(update)


resetax = plt.axes([0.8, 0.025, 0.1, 0.04])
button = Button(resetax, 'Reset', color=axcolor, hovercolor='0.975')

def reset(event):
    sa.reset()
button.on_clicked(reset)

plt.show()
```

As I said, this code works like a charm, but how could I "save" the result? I have thought on making an html-js version, but couldn't make a Bokeh similar version for it and mpld3 doesn't seem to support sliders...

Thanks in advance,

Javirk

Comment: put the code online somewhere? im not sure how you think rewriting in js would change anything

Comment: You can make a quiver plot using `multi_line` with Bokeh (relevant code at the end): http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/dev/docs/gallery/quiver.html But to make an interactive app that runs python code when buttons are clicked, etc. you have the same issue: the app needs to be permanently run and hosted somewhere.

Comment: Thank you, bigreddot. 

Yes, I had seen that code and I have rewritten it to fit my functions. Without a slider everything works perfectly fine (the phase portrait I want to obtain is accurate) but I don't really see how to add the slider and make it work. I should change U and V in the callback function but that changes the xs and ys, which come from a python function (streamlines) so I think I've come to a dead end.

I'll have to keep on thinking, all help is very appreciated though.

Answer (score 1):

finally I could figure it out myself. I had to use "segment" instead of "multi_line" because I didn't want to set up a server. The code:

```
from __future__ import division

import numpy as np

from bokeh.layouts import row, widgetbox
from bokeh.models import CustomJS, Slider
from bokeh.plotting import figure, output_file, show, ColumnDataSource

#Declaration of variables 

xx = np.linspace(0, 1, 50)
yy = np.linspace(0, 1, 50)

Y, X = np.meshgrid(xx, yy)

x0 = X[::2, ::2].flatten()
y0 = Y[::2, ::2].flatten()

#Equations and so, result: x1,y1 with same dimensions as x0,y0
#x1,y1 are the coordinates of the final point of the segment

source = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(x0=x0, y0=y0, x1=x1, y1=y1))

#Plot
plot = figure(x_range=(0, 1), y_range=(0, 1), x_axis_label='H', y_axis_label='C',
              title="Retrato de fases. Modelo simplificado")
plot.segment('x0', 'y0', 'x1', 'y1', source=source, line_width=1)

#JS function that activates when slider value is changed
callback = CustomJS(args=dict(source=source), code="""
    var data = source.data;
    var alpha = alpha.value;

    x0 = data['x0'];
    y0 = data['y0'];
    x1 = data['x1'];
    y1 = data['y1'];

    for (i = 0; i < x0.length; i++) {
        #Same equations as before, but written in JS
    }
    source.trigger('change');
""")

#Set up all the sliders
alfa_slider = Slider(start=0, end=1, value=alpha, step=.01, title="Alpha", callback=callback)
callback.args["alpha"] = alpha_slider

output_file("slider.html", title="Phase Portrait")

layout = row(
    plot,
    widgetbox(alpha_slider),
)
show(layout)
```